# Transformers 3 teaser trailer sound

Tags: transformers, effects

This has been driving me crazy for a while.  The effects sequence at the end of this trailer has me stumped.  It's so intricate and the sounds evolve so quickly, I'm having trouble figuring out how they did this.  Any ideas?  It's the end sequence where the camera zooms in on the robot's eye, and then ends in an exploding title sequence, starting at around 2:04.

Any ideas?  It all sounds kind of granular to me, so maybe sounds that have been granularized?  Ideas are welcome and appreciated.

[Here's the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H8bnKdf654)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRM Tools and Metasynth are some others they probably used.  I'm pretty such Dane used both on The Matrix and I know GRM can create similar type sounds.  Probably lots of recorded servos and motor sounds that were made smaller too.  Fluttering is something they do a lot and Mondo Mod can be tweaked to make some pretty good flutter effects.

Comment: Ooh yeah, the fluttering.  I'm actually experimenting with some foley glass sounds that I recorded myself, timestretching it in Ableton to make it all granular sounding, then running it through some flangers, some tremolo and autopan.  Very very interesting results.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Guess it could be done with alot  of different kind of processing, but it sounds alot like Kyma processing to me. 
Take a look at this site: http://jedsound.com/blog/
And scroll down through the examples found there. Very similar, and many had Kyma involved I believe.

Best wishes, Mikkel

Comment: Kyma.  I was afraid you were going to say something like that.  That's a bit out of my price range, I'm afraid.  Thanks for your answer though!  :)

Comment: I think you can get there with some plugins like grm tools etc, the right sounds and some hard work:o

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, processing aside, it's around 50-odd discrete sound elements chained together. Here's a video on some of the sound effects work done on the film which may lend some clues: ["Soundworks Collection"](http://soundworkscollection.com/transformers3)

Comment: Thanks for posting that, really great video. Love the electric guitar stuff and the dry ice in the metal air vent.

Answer (score 0):

iZotope's Stutter Edit can also be used to create this flutter/stutter effect.